# Android Contact Picker with only Phone Numbers

Tags: android, android-contacts

I found on SO that to launch a filtered version of contact picker (which only shows contacts that have phone numbers), I can just use this:

```
Intent pickContactIntent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI );
pickContactIntent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
startActivityForResult(pickContactIntent, CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT);
```

So this works. I'm just trying to figure out how to retrieve the name and phone number of the selected contact now, within the onActivityResult method:

```
@Override  
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     // what goes here...
}
```

I've tried a number of different things inside onActivityResult, but the queries don't return the number.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pick a Number and Name From Contacts List in android app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496350/pick-a-number-and-name-from-contacts-list-in-android-app)

Comment: when i open the contact picker like this , the cursor i get is always empty. What can it be ?

Answer (score 32):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI);  
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

String phoneNo = null;
Uri uri = data.getData();
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    int phoneIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
    phoneNo = cursor.getString(phoneIndex);
}

curosr.close();
```

Comment: Super works for me too,, please mark it as right answer.

Comment: getColumnIndex returns -1 `cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)` 
Is this normal?

Comment: For Android  11+, changes in AndroidManifest file like https://stackoverflow.com/a/67600033/1889825

Answer (score 9):

Building on Akash's answer.

***Step 1*** - need to add Read/Write contact permissions in Manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<!-- OR - depends on the requiremnts-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
```

***Step 2*** - then need to launch contact picker intent, but before that need to check if Contact permission is granted (only for Android >=23)

```
if (hasPermissions(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI);
      startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PICK_CONTACT);
} else {
     // Request Permissions
}
```

***Step 3*** - then need to get Activity Result

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_PICK_CONTACT) {
         String phoneNo = null;
         String name = null;

         Uri uri = data.getData();
         Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);

         if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
         int phoneIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
         int nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);

         phoneNo = cursor.getString(phoneIndex);
         name = cursor.getString(nameIndex);

         Log.e("onActivityResult()", phoneIndex + " " + phoneNo + " " + nameIndex + " " + name);
      }
      cursor.close();
  }
}
```

And yeah thats it.