# How to call the system app for contacts' detail

Tags: android, contacts

I known the following code can call the system activity for contact list.

```
public void showSystemContactsUI(int requestCode) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
}
```

My question is how to call the system UI for the contacts' details, as the attached screenshot, Thx.[image]

Comment: what is your purpose to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following code snippet. You would need to find target contact id before showing its details.

```
Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(uri, "1"); // 1 is contact id
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: It works, Thank you. One more question if don't mind,  if replace startActivity(intent) with startActivityForResult,  Is it possible to pass the picked number back instead of dialling it. I have tried replace Intent.ACTION_VIEW with Intent.ACTION_PICK, but did not work.

Comment: You can follow this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496350/pick-a-number-and-name-from-contacts-list-in-android-app.

Answer (score 0):

Create class call it **IntentHelper** and put all of related function to your systems (e.g **Dial-Number** , **Send-SMS** , **View-in-Browser** , ... ) in that like this :

```
public class IntentHelper {


    public static void dialNumber(Context context, String number) {
        if (((TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).getPhoneType() != TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_NONE) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.fromParts("tel", number, null));
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    public static void sendEmail(Context context, String email) {
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts("mailto", email, null));
        context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));
    }


    public static void viewInBrowser(Context context, String url) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        if (null != intent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager())) {
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    public static void shareOnSocials(Context context, String videoUrl) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, videoUrl);
        context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "share on "));
    }

}
```